# Is there any way that the collection could be modified in this foreach loop?

Tags: c#

An error gets thrown that the collection gets modified during the foreach loop.

Considering the only thing that happens in the foreach loop is a method, in which I pass a string. I cannot find a way in which the collection 'cards' could possibly be changed during the loop, regardless of what happens inside the method.

I would like to know if any of you have a definition for the ExcludeCard method that could change the cards collection.

After some great comments by others, I would like to add that this method is called by another class. The Lack method has no way of referring back to the class that called it.

```
public void Lack(List<string> cards, int playerIndex)
{
    foreach (string card in cards)
    {
        ExcludeCard(card, playerIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the implementation of `ExcludeCard`? If it's changing the same list that's passed to `Lack` then you would be modifying the collection in a foreach loop.

Comment: @JonathonChase The implementation is somewhat lengthy, I do not change the card parameter. But I was thinking that it doesn't matter what the implementation is, because it cannot alter the collection if it only gets passed a string of one item in the collection. (strings are effectively passed by value, as I understand it)

Comment: You should create a [MCVE] that actually demonstrates this. That should guide you on what parts of `ExcludeCard` would be necessary to include in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cause this error to occur trivially if your implementation of `ExcludeCard` modifies the collection that is passed to your `Lack` method. This is because a `List<T>` is passed by reference, so you you would be acting on a collection that's currently being enumerated.

The following will cause the issue:

```
void Main()
{
    Lack(Cards, 0);
}

public List<string> Cards = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();

public void Lack(List<string> cards, int playerIndex)
{
    foreach (string card in cards)
    {
        ExcludeCard(card, playerIndex);
    }
}

public void ExcludeCard(string card, int playerIndex) 
{
    Cards.Remove(card);
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent example of why it's best to use referential stateless programming wherever possible.  Referential stateless methods only operate on the arguments passed to them. They do not read or write to any other class members, which makes it extremely easy to reason about them.  If you pass in the same parameters multiple times, you will always get exactly the same result.  Makes unit testing easy also.

Comment: I see what you mean, this is indeed a function that could modify the collection. I appreciate your help; however, in my code the function is called from another class. The class with the Lack method does not have a reference to the class that called the method. Therefore it also doesn't have a reference to the List<string> cards. I should have included it in the original question, my bad. The project is at: https://github.com/mchl12/CluedoAI I am talking about GameForm calling Lack in Tracker.I do not expect you to look at the project, but you can if that helps you understand this comment.

Comment: I would like to add that after a bit more searching through my code, now keeping in mind the ways that I might unexpectedly change the collection. What I said in my previous comment is not entirely true, through some way, dating back to some actions earlier it was possible to change the collection. I will not give more details because they will be useless to others. Many thanks for this example implementation. The question could be considered solved.

Comment: @mchl12 So what you're saying is that the example of what was wrong given in this answer was correct? Then you should accept the answer: that signals to everyone else that you found a solution.